# Newbie. PHP How to extract array's last element's key value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example, I have an array:

```
$result = array(
array (
      'post_id'=>$post_id,
      'user_id'=>90,
),
array (
      'post_id'=>$post_id,
      'user_id'=>80,
),
.....

}
```

And I'd like to get the last $result element's key value - (e.g user_id = 10) 10. Is it somehow possible to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`end`](http://www.php.net/end) for this

```
$end = end($result);
print $end['post_id'];//etc.
```

This will also reset the internal pointer of the array, so if you use `current`, `next` or anything similar after that, you'll need to `reset` first.

Comment: Thanks so much, one headache less!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`end()`][1] for this

```
$last_id=end($result)['used_id'];
```

However, if you're doing anything with array pointers, you'll need to either `reset()` it, or use `$last_id=end(array_values($result))`
[1]: https://www.php.net/end